# Shortest sequence to make math expression match a target number

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am going through eloquent JavaScript and there is a program checking if any combination of multiplying 3 and adding 5 produces the target value or not:

But this function does not give me the shortest possible (sequence) for this.

I cannot think of the logic to get the shortest possible solution. How can I change this code to give me the shortest path?

```js
function find_solution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (target === current) {
      return history;
    } else if (target < current) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) || find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, '1');
}

console.log(find_solution(24));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good effort. You're running a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), but DFS doesn't always give you the shortest path. [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) is a good naive first option for finding the shortest path. Optimization may be necessary.

```js
const shortestPathAddMul = (target, begin=1, add=5, mul=3) => {
  const visited = new Set();
  
  for (const q = [[begin, begin]]; q.length;) {
    const [seq, curr] = q.shift();
    
    if (visited.has(curr)) continue;
    
    visited.add(curr);

    if (curr === target) {
      return `${seq} = ${target}`;
    }
    else if (curr < target) {
      q.push(...[[`(${seq} + ${add})`, curr + add],
                 [`(${seq} * ${mul})`, curr * mul]]);
    }
  }
};

console.log(shortestPathAddMul(24));
```